# Compute $\|A(t)\|$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

When I do my homework (**stability theory**), I must use the knowledge to the **norm of matrix**. But I don't remember it (I mean that I'm not sure).

**My problem**:

For matrix $A(t)$ is continuous. Compute $\|A(t)\|, (t \in \mathbb{R})$, where:
$$A(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
& 0&1\\ 
& -f(t)&0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Here's my solution:

- I find $$A^T=\begin{pmatrix}
  & 0&-f(t)\\ 
  & 1&0 
  \end{pmatrix}$$
- I compute $$A^TA=\begin{pmatrix}
  & f^2(t)&0\\ 
  & 0&1 
  \end{pmatrix}$$
- Applying $$\bf{\boxed{\|A\|=\max_{i=1,2}\sqrt{\lambda_i{(A^TA)}}}}$$, where $\lambda_i{(A^TA)}$ is the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue of $A^TA$. So $\lambda_1{(A^TA)}=1, \lambda_2{(A^TA)}=f^2(t)$.

Hence, $\|A\|=|f(t)|$. Is it correct?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What if $f(t) = \frac12$?

Comment: I mean $$\max \{|f(t)|,1\}=|f(t)|; \text{if} |f(t)| \ge 1 \text{and} \max \{|f(t)|,1\}=1; \text{if} |f(t)| <1 $$

Comment: Yep, you get $\lVert A(t)\rVert = \max \{ 1,\,\lvert f(t)\rvert\}$.

Comment: You mean I'm correct (when I compute $\|A\|$).  **Daniel Fischer**

Comment: Except in the penultimate line, where you wrote $\lVert A\rVert = \lvert f(t)\rvert$.

Comment: Wow! Hihi! :) I didn't write carefully! Thank you very much! **Daniel Fischer**